# change check another radio option using jquery 1.7.X

Tags: jquery

i've tried all methods to uncheck the first option of a radio button and check the last option, here is the html form

http://jsfiddle.net/n5AdN/2/

```
$('#use_for_shipping_yes').prop('checked', false);
$('#use_for_shipping_store').prop('checked', true);
```

I want to change to check the last option, how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your id selector is wrong, the id of the element is `billing:use_for_shipping_store`, so

```
$('#billing\\:use_for_shipping_store').prop('checked', true);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hrG6p/)

You need to escape the `:` in the id using `\:` for the [selector to work](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 0):

you can include checked="checked" for the last option in the html.
 html:

```
<input type="radio" name="billing[use_for_shipping]" id="billing:use_for_shipping_store" value="1" checked="checked" onclick="$('shipping:same_as_billing').checked = true;">
```

Refer the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/n5AdN/3/